# Is Doodle God on Windows Phone different from other platforms, aside from the exclusive add-on?

Tags: windows-phone, doodle-god

After struggling for awhile in Doodle God on my Windows Phone, I finally gave in and started looking for walkthroughs. However, some of the formulas I've found in walkthroughs don't seem to work in my version of the game.

The following are said to work in "Episode 1" but so far don't work for me.

- Human + Human = Sex
- Fire + Grass = Tobacco
- Alcohol + Water = Vodka

Is this due to some difference between Doodle God in Windows Phone and the others? I'm aware the Windows Phone version includes an exclusive add-on, "20th Century Greatest Inventions", but I wouldn't figure this should affect the rest of the game.

Or is there just some other less-documented milestone in the game I need to hit? I haven't made 100 elements yet.

EDIT: I'm now into what I think is "Episode 3" (currently 148/180 elements). Still can't do the above combinations, though.

Comment: I can verify that these combinations do NOT work on Windows Phone.